# Leading thermal corrections to Lindhard susceptibility

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory

I am interested in deriving the leading temperature-dependent correction to the zero-temperature static Lindhard susceptibility of a homogeneous free electron gas. My starting point is the following expression for the susceptibility:
$$
\chi(k) = -\frac{1}{\pi^2 k} \int_0^\infty  \ln\left|\frac{2q + k}{2q - k}\right| q f(q^2/2) dq
$$
where $k$ is the magnitude of momentum, $f(\epsilon)$ is the Fermi-Dirac occupancy, and atomic units ($\hbar=m_e=1$) are used. The zero-temperature limit is straightforward to obtain by replacing $f(\epsilon)$ with a step function.

It seems natural enough to do a Sommerfeld-style treatment of the integral to obtain $O(\beta^{-2})$ thermal corrections. First, I change variables from momentum to energy:
$$
\chi(x) = -\frac{1}{\pi^2 k} \int_0^\infty \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{8\epsilon} + k}{\sqrt{8\epsilon} -k}\right| f(\epsilon) d\epsilon
$$
Naively, I expand (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_expansion):
$$
\chi(k) \sim -\frac{1}{\pi^2 k} \int_0^\mu \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{8\epsilon} + k}{\sqrt{8\epsilon} -k}\right| d\epsilon - \frac{1}{6k\beta^2} \frac{d}{d\mu} \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{8\mu} + k}{\sqrt{8\mu} -k}\right| \equiv \chi_0(k) + \chi_T(k)
$$
Evaluating the thermal correction, I find it is singular at $k = \sqrt{8\mu} ~(=2k_F)$:
$$
\chi_T(k) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3\beta^2\sqrt{\mu}} \frac{1}{k^2 - 8\mu}
$$
I suspect the non-analyticity of integrand at $k=2k_F$ is to blame here. Some condition for the applicability of the naive Sommerfeld expansion has been violated, and an unphysical answer is the result.

Is there a way to navigate the logarithmic singularity to produce a sensible thermal correction to the zero-temperature Lindhard susceptibility?

Comment: Suggestions for relevant tags are much appreciated!